# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 298]

Tags: python

I try reproduce example of video classification from here
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/deep-learning-video-classification-python/

When i train create validate sample

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)    # preparing
```

the validation set

, i get the error

```
>>> X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=
0.3, random_state=42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Константин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pack
ages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2184, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "C:\Users\Константин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pack
ages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 260, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "C:\Users\Константин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-pack
ages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 298]
```

i found on SO simiral topic
[ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7111, 1778]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311793/valueerror-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-7111-1)

but the decision didn't help me.
How to do correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the mismatch of the shape of the array `dummy_y`.
The train_test_split() expects an array of matching number of rows.

Hence the `dummy_array` must be flattened.
Documentation [np.flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.htmlhttps://)

*Try the below code*

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = \
    train_test_split(X, dummy_y.flatten(), test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

It would be great if you can share some more information about the variables(type, shape etc.).